# collecting multiple GET or POST values

Tags: php, html

I have a form that passes something like in a URL

```
?choice=selection+A&choice=selection+C
```

I'm collecting it in a form with something like (I remember that $_GET is any array)

```
        $temp = $_GET["choice"];
    print_r($temp);
```

I'm only getting the last instance "selection C". What am I missing

Comment: wow - that was fast. Thanks works a treat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming 'choice' is some kind of multi-select or checkbox group? If so, change its name in your html to 'choice[]'. $_GET['choice'] will then be an array of the selections the user made.

Comment: You would definetly use this method when you want to collect multiple options of the same group (like any array of checkboxes or a select that allows multiple choices)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't intend to edit the HTML, this will allow you to do what you're looking to do; it will populate the `$_REQUEST` superglobal and overwrite its contents.

This assumes PHP Version 5.3, because it uses the Ternary Shortcut Operator.  This can be removed.

```
$rawget = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : false;
$rawpost = file_get_contents('php://input') ?: false;
$target = $rawget;
$_REQUEST = array();
if ($target !== false) {
    $pairs = explode('&',$rawget);
    foreach($pairs as $pair) {
        $p = strpos($pair,'=');
        if ($p === false && !empty($pair)) {
            $_REQUEST[$pair] = null;
        }
        elseif ($p === 0 || empty($pair)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            list($name, $value) = explode('=',$pair,2);
            $name = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/','',urldecode($name));
            $value = urldecode($value);
            if (array_key_exists($name, $_REQUEST)) {
                if (is_array($_REQUEST[$name])) {
                    $_REQUEST[$name][] = $value;
                }
                else {
                    $_REQUEST[$name] = array($_REQUEST[$name], $value);
                }
            }
            else {
                $_REQUEST[$name] = $value;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it stands, this will only process the QueryString/GET variables; to process post as well, change the 3rd line to something like

```
$target = ($rawget ?: '') . '&' . ($rawpost ?: '');
```

All that having been said, I'd still recommend changing the HTML, but if that's not an option for whatever reason, then this should do it.